# Can someone undelete my question?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-undelete

I just read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) that says users with high reputation can undelete questions. I hope I'm doing things right, since it's unclear to me how am I supposed to ask for "undeletion".

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797180/what-is-the-difference-between-fopen-modes-r-and-rw-in-php) was deleted by the "Community" user, because it received -2 votes and it's been 30 days since it was reopened (it was closed due to downvotes).

However one might (not) like my question, it certainly fulfills all criteria to be a question here. The reasons are as follows:

1. Many users on Stack Overflow use the undocumented `"rw+"` PHP mode in their answers;
2. I'm asking what this undocumented mode does;
3. I only received 2 answers: check the documentation (I posted the link to the documentation in my original question - there's nothing there about this), and that the `"rw+"` mode is a *combination* of the `r` and `w+` modes (it isn't, so this answer is **wrong**). Therefore, it still has no answers, and no one that commented my question had a correct answer for it.

Could someone please undelete it? I still want to know the answer and I do think it's a relevant question for other users (even though some might, apparently, hate it).

---

I uploaded an image of the question, with all comments expanded: [image: link]

Comment: Yep, undeleted. I am not sure how/why it was deleted, to be honest. Thanks for bringing it here.

Comment: If we undelete it what's to stop the Roomba deleting it again?

Comment: @halfer Thanks for undeleting!:) And also for all the previous help. It seems that the "Community" user deletes automatically all questions with a negative score after 30 days. So RobertLongson's question is very pertinent, I don't know what will stop it from automatically deleting the question next month

Comment: An edit that would improve this question, and which I alluded to in the comment stream, is a full runnable PHP script that demonstrates how the modes are different. Could you add that? It might make it a bit more concrete.

Comment: @halfer It's actually quite easy, just something like: `<?php $file = somefilewith.data; fopen($file, "rw+"); fwrite($file, "data");?>`. Like I said in the edit, `w+` truncates the file, `rw+` does not truncate it. This answer, for example, will not work it `rw+` is substituted for `w+`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815150/4621141 . I can put this in the question if you think it will help, but it seems to be a bit redundant for me, since all it's only purpose is to show that one mode truncates the file while the other doesn't

Comment: No, a full script would (a) do two sets of runs, and (b) contain a comparison statement to show how the output files are different. I would like to see something that people can copy and paste into their editor, run, and see the difference in `echo` statements. Part of the problem might be that this feels somewhat esoteric, and unless a reader is particularly invested in the bug, they probably won't want to do the remaining legwork to see if you are correct.

Comment: @halfer To be honest, I'd rather not post my script, at least all of it. But the tiny script above and the script in the answer already fail if one tries them. I don't see why someone would not test them, but prefer to test a larger script. Although the tiny script is *wrong* (sigh)... Sorry, I'm very tired, I still haven't slept and it's almost 7 AM here. I'll edit now the question with a script that serves as a test for our fellow users. And you're right, it's important to leave a handy test for others.

Comment: OK, thanks for adding that, that looks excellent.

Comment: 25 points now... so meta effect!

Comment: @Cœur 40. That is not the meta effect but the lemming effect :/

Comment: Still cannot believe 2 random ignorant people can decide what happens with hours of my work to write up a decent post.

Comment: @DaniSpringer The 5 weeks without an answer, along with the lack of any upvotes, also played a fairly significant role...

Comment: @Dukeling I'm sure, but it happens also without that.

Comment: @DaniSpringer general problem on the stack sites IMO: Have lost count of the times I've found helpful questions closed or otherwise tampered with.

Comment: @Erik that's a very commonly heard complaint (on Reddit and so on), but never backed up with sources. Please try to find one and link it, we'll be happy to explain what is wrong with that question.

Comment: I have seen it for myself, again and again. Now that you mention it I can't remember last time I saw this but I guess there is a reason why I (and as you mention: reddit, I'm not a redditor) remember this. If stack* has stopped doing this then great.